# PostgresQL Query elapsed time in SELECT return

Tags: postgresql

My PostgreSQL query only returns one row and I need to include in the SELECT the amount of time it took to return.

How do I do this?

E.g. Table `hello`

```
SELECT COUNT(h.*) as "count", <insert query time calculation here> as "elapsed_ms"
FROM hello h;
```

Kind regards

Comment: Why not measure the time in the program that issues the query?

Comment: That would make sense, but we are building a DB driven API, so I need to simply just pop back results. The more things I can get in my SQL command, the more it will comply to what my company is trying to do.

Comment: Are you using directly in `psql` terminal? Or inside a language? There are different approaches in different scenarios

Comment: I don't think you can get this done in your SQL command. The thing that would come closest is `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`, but afaik there's no way to get the actual result rows from that.

Comment: The amount of time it took *what* to return *what*?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this in one single SQL statement because PostgreSQL does not expose system function or system column in SQL to retrieve current query execution time (function `statement_timestamp()` can be used for query start but there is no corresponding function for query end).

But you could try something like  this in a function:

```
create function exec_count() 
returns table (ccount int, ctime_microsec int) 
language plpgsql
as
$$
declare
 v_begin timestamp;
 v_end timestamp;
 v_s int;
 v_mls int;
 v_mcs int;
 v_count int;
 v_time int;
begin
 v_begin = clock_timestamp();
 select count(*) into v_count from hello h;
 v_end = clock_timestamp();
 select extract(microseconds from (v_end - v_begin)) into v_mcs;
 select extract(milliseconds from (v_end - v_begin)) into v_mls;
 select extract(second from v_end - v_begin) into v_s;
 v_time = v_mcs + v_mls*1000 * v_s*1000*1000;
 return query select v_count, v_time;
end;
$$;
```

You could call the function in SQL instead of the query:

```
select * from exec_count();
 ccount | ctime_microsec 
--------+----------------
    457 |            407
(1 row)
```

This function computes execution time in microseconds and assumes the query does *not* take more than 60 seconds.

Comment: I guess you can extract `epoch` instead of `seconds` from the interval to make it work for larger values